# Do PageSpeed Insights vary by location?

Tags: page-speed, google-pagespeed

I'm testing my own website using google page speed insights API with the following URL https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://hazemhagrass.com&strategy=desktop
I tried to test it from different machines all over the world, I'm wondering why I'm getting different scores based on location! Sometimes I got speed score 78 and 83 in the same time from other machine hosted on other location. Any Ideas!
[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Pagespeed and other performance testing sites will report different results depending on your location, since the network routing across the internet to get to your specific web server will vary.

1. [GT Metrix has a great blog post explaining this behavior.](https://gtmetrix.com/blog/the-difference-between-gtmetrix-pagespeed-insights-pingdom-tools-and-webpagetest/)
2. [Google's own documentation (from the legacy standalone Pagespeed web site tester) also describes this here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/tryit)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I believe that webpagetest is the one mentioned in Google’s documentation not generic google page speed insights test. Correct?

Comment: You are correct, the Pagespeed standalone web page testing service is deprecated, not the API itself for Pagespeed Insight reporting.

Comment: So we can’t say that the service is disabled and we have to still consider its results

Comment: Answer edited/updated to better indicate the point of referencing the second article. Good catch!